# Pushing items on stack and logging the current stack in a for(each) loop

Tags: javascript

I've got the following problem and I can't seem to get why it's not working the way I think it should be working:

```
function iterate(somelist){  
    anotherlist = [];
    for(i = 0; i < somelist.length; i++){  
       anotherlist.push(somelist[i]);
       console.log(anotherlist);
    }
}
```

What I would expect this to do is log an increasingly growing list, but instead it just prints the complete list several times, as if it first pushes all variable into anotherlist and afterwards starts the log function. It doesn't seem to matter wether I use a for or a foreach loop.

I really don't get why it works like this and can't seem to figure out a way to work around it.

Thanks in advance,
Bart

By the way, somelist in this case is an object on which I iterate, and it seems to make a difference, as I tried it with a normal array and that seems to work.

Comment: WebKit's console exhibits the issue even on a standard array for me, as I would expect it to.  The differences between arrays and objects are negligible here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the console waits for the thread to finish before updating, perhaps so as not to interfere with performance too much.  When the console UI is finally updated, the thread (and loop) has already finished and all logs reference the same array.

To work around it, you can call the array's `slice()` method to make a copy of the array whilst logging:

```
function iterate(somelist){  
    anotherlist = [];
    for(i = 0; i < somelist.length; i++){  
       anotherlist.push(somelist[i]);
       console.log(anotherlist.slice());
    }
}

var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
iterate(test);
//-> [1]
//-> [1, 2]
//-> [1, 2, 3]
//-> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! This exactly what I was looking for! I'm used to logging only synchronizing threads, not waiting with logging untill the complete thread is done. Specifically I need the subarray for the next iteration, which just didn't seem to work right the way I tried it :)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to console log the new list

```
console.log(anotherlist);
```

Comment: Sorry :) but that's what I meant to post. *changed the original post

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it you are getting confused about for(;;) and for(in) loops.

**For loops** are just the same old loop you know from C, Java or basically any language out there. Create a loop variable, increment it, etc.

Of course, you probably can't iterate over an object with a for-loop though because you need to have a .length property...

**for(in) loops are *not* foreach loops!** (This confusion is a very common Javascript trap)

for-in iterates over object *properties* and thus should only be used to iterate on Objects, not array. For example:

```
var xs = {
   a : 1,
   b : 2
};
for(var i in xs){
    console.log(i, xs[i])
}
```

will print

```
'a', 1
'b', 2
```